# Cloud function fails with "missing ) after argument list at wrapSafe"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm in the process of splitting my cloud functions in separate files, so as to lazy load some dependencies and reduce cold start.

Basically, I'm trying to replicate Doug's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726668/how-do-i-lazy-load-dependencies-for-cloud-functions-that-are-split-in-single-fil), but not having to create a separate file for each function.

In my index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const { createUser } = require('./user/main');
  await createUser(user, admin);
});
```

And in my 'user/main.js' file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Stripe } = require('stripe');
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.secret);
const endpointSecret = functions.config().stripe.singing;

const createStripeCustomer = async (user, admin) => {
  // Do some stuff
};

module.exports = { createUser: createStripeCustomer };
```

The intention behind this split, is that I have some functions which require Stripe, and some which do not, hence I don't want them all to load it unnecessarily, but I get an error- "missing ) after argument list".

Any suggestions as to what has gone wrong?

Comment: The error message should have a line number that shows where the error happened.

Comment: Error message: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18) "

Comment: So look at line 915 of `loader.js`.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can find that file, as it's some sort of an internal Cloud Functions file? (I'm seeing the error in the "Logs" section of the Firebase Functions Console, if that makes any difference)

Comment: The error message has the path to the file.

Comment: I don't know anything about the specifics of Cloud Functions.

Comment: If this is happening in a script you didn't write, it's probably expecting a newer version of node.js than what you're running.

Comment: I see. Will play around with it to see if I can get round it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not look like the real solution...

Maybe you also fixed something which looked insignificant... Like an extra double quote.

```js
let something = "A"
console.log("hello", something")
```

See the extra double quote after the variable?

It produces the same error you mentionned.

It is a common error due to code editors just adding thing for you... And if you are like me and look at the keyboard instead of the screen, it is easy not to notice.

Comment: That's what I thought initially as well, and went over the code 5 or 6 times, but still couldn't find the culprit. Anyway, it's all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone experiences a similar problem, I managed to get it working, simply by changing:

```
const createStripeCustomer = async (user, admin) => {
  // Do some stuff
};
```

to:

```
async function createStripeCustomer(user, admin) {
  // Do some stuff
};
```

I have no idea why that was an issue, but it seemed to resolve the problem I had before.